# How to generate primitive root modulo n using OpenSSL?

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, elgamal

I need to generate primitive root modulo n for ElGamal cryptosystem, where n - is big prime number. How can I generate it using OpenSSL?

Is there special function like primitive_root(...)? I didn't found enything like this.

Comment: I did not find any such function in my perusal.

Comment: You can use [NTL](https://www.shoup.net/ntl/) library, [here](https://saadquader.wordpress.com/2017/08/25/finding-primitive-roots-of-unity-in-a-finite-field-c-code-using-ntl/) example.

Comment: There is `BN_mod_sqrt` which takes the *square* root, but I guess that's not what you are looking for.